# how to redirect to view with user data after logout using larravel

Tags: laravel, redirect

I'm working on an exams app using Laravel
And the tester upon completion of the test must be logged out programmatically and redirected after logging out to display the test result

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your controller...

```
use Auth;
```

Then in your function...

```
Auth::logout();
return redirect()->route('testresults.show')->with([ 'results' => $results ]);
```